# How to read parsed JSON from text in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to read the following JSON text from my fetched database, below was my sample code:

```
{{questionData1[0].qst_cnt_options[0].left}}
```

The real data in `qst_cnt_options` was:

```
[{left:'Benda Hidup',right:'Benda Mati'}] //Fetched from database and as text
```

When I tried to read back, the output was only
`[`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: show the content of the file, and the code you are having issues with ... so far you've shown fragments of something that makes little sense

Comment: `{{questionData1[0].JSON.parse(qst_cnt_options)[0].left}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the fetched value from the database is simple text, use `JSON.parse` to parse into a json object and retrieve it.

`[{left:'Benda Hidup',right:'Benda Mati'}]` this is a string, so returning `[` as first value.

**Method1:**
just return the JSON parsed value from the contrller,

In your controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.qst_cnt_options =  $scope.questionData1[0].JSON.parse(qst_cnt_options)
});
```

In your view:

**`{{qst_cnt_options[0].left}}`**

**Method2:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.qst_cnt_options =  questionData1[0].JSON.parse(qst_cnt_options)

    $scope.parJson = function (json) {
            return JSON.parse(json)[0];
    }
});
```

View:

`{{qst_cnt_options.parJson(qst_cnt_options.qst_cnt_options)}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible directly to code in angular view?

Comment: no but you can use a function in the view, which you can use to parse in the controller. Updating the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer, but you cannot use `JSON.parse` in the view, I prefer the first method.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Encapsulate the strings (including left, right) with double quotes. That should sort it out.

It might appear that what you are fetching back isn't resolving as proper JSON because of surrounding [] which might be forcing the parser to treat it as an Array.

Try removing the [] and see if that works

I ran further checks on the input and as per the JSON validators you should be encapsulating your strings in double quotes. There are no quotes around left and right qualifiers. That might be your problem.

Try the online validator here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I need to put in `[]` so my codes would be extensible

Comment: I need to try first. Thanks for the answer.